# GroupBy value of ObservableCollection items

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
    class MyClassDetails
    {
        public int Value;
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            moreDetails = new ObservableCollection<MyClassDetails>();
        }
        public string Name;
        public ObservableCollection<MyClassDetails> moreDetails;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<MyClass>();

        var myClass1 = new MyClass();
        myClass1.Name = "Class1";
        myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 1 });
        myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 2 });
        myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 4 });
        myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 16 });

        var myClass2 = new MyClass();
        myClass2.Name = "Class2";
        myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 1 });
        myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 2 });
        myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 4 });
        myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 16 });

        myList.Add(myClass1);
        myList.Add(myClass2);


        var groups1 = myList.GroupBy(myClass => myClass.Name);//This groups by class Name
        foreach(var group in groups1)
        {
            var key = group.Key;//key is e.g 'Class1'/'Class2'
        }

       //does not work??
        var groups2 = myList.GroupBy(myClass => myClass.moreDetails)
                            .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.ToList().Distinct().Count() });
        foreach (var group in groups2)
        {
            //WTF??
        }
    }
```

How can I group the original myList into groups where the Key is the Value e.g. 1,2,4,16 ans I know the total count of each value.
So for the following I would end up with 4 groups:

```
Group 1 Key=1 Value=2
Group 2 Key=2 Value=2
Group 3 Key=4 Value=2
Group 4 Key=16 Value=2
```

So basically its How many different 'Value's are there are and what is the count of each in myList

**UPDATE QUESTION**
I now have added the following ID to MyClassDetails class.

```
class MyClassDetails
{
    public string ID;  <--Added ID
    public int Value;
}

var myList = new List<MyClass>();

var myClass1 = new MyClass();
myClass1.Name = "Class1";
myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 1, ID="ONE" });
myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 2, ID = "TWO" });
myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 4, ID = "ONE" });
myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 8, ID = "TWO" });
myClass1.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 16, ID = "ONE" });

var myClass2 = new MyClass();
myClass2.Name = "Class2";
myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 1, ID = "TWO" });
myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 2, ID = "ONE" });
myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 4, ID = "ONE" });
myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 8, ID = "TWO" });
myClass2.moreDetails.Add(new MyClassDetails() { Value = 54, ID = "ONE" });

myList.Add(myClass1);
myList.Add(myClass2);
```

How do I modify the query given in the answer so I only count the Distinct Values by ID.

So for the above the Value= 4 and Value=8 would only have count=1 as they have the same ID values.

Comment: Updated with example thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first select the details that you want into multiple objects and then group those objects

```
var groups2 = myList.SelectMany(myClass => myClass.moreDetails, (myClass, details) => new { details.Value, myClass.moreDetails} )
                    .GroupBy(myClass => myClass.Value)
                    .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.ToList().Distinct().Count() });
```

Comment: Perfect.  One more question, how can I go one step further and only return the ones for e.g. "Name=Class1" ?

Comment: You can add a where clause before the SelectMany to filter out the list

Comment: Thanks, I have just added a follow up question to your original answer.

Comment: `Thanks, I have just added a follow up question to your original answer.` That would be best as a new post / question.